# Why does "new vector<int>[5]" not create an array of vectors?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

I have a code snippet that aims to create an array of vectors using the keyword "new". The addresss thus returned by new is assigned to a pointer of type vector.

```
vector<vector<int>> *adj = new vector<vector<int>>[V]; // creates a 2-D vector

vector<vector<int>> *adj = new vector<vector<int>>[V]; //creates a 1-D vector
```

Drawing analogy from built-in data type array creation,

```
int *arr = new int[V]; //creates an array of integers
```

the code below should create an array of integer-containing vectors

```
vector<int> *arr = new vector<int>[V]; //should create an array of vectors
```

But what it actually creates is a vector of ints.

Am I missing something here that relates to STLs and iterators being assigned to the pointer?

Comment: `int *arr = new int(5);` creates one `int` with the value 5.

Comment: why do you want to do this? `vector<vector<int>>(5,vector<int>(5,0))` would create a vector with 5x5 vector each value initialised to 0. You can use the `resize` to adjust size dynamically if you have to, I don't see the need for a new.

Comment: The title of the question does not match the body. The code in the title **does** create an array of vectors.

Comment: If i can edit my question, please replace all circular brackets with square ones. I was not able to edit the question once i posted it.

Comment: Please re-read the question, I have corrected the brackets. Thanks.

Comment: @Samuel Tufail, I am trying to create an array of vectors and I want to assign the address thus generated by new to a pointer.

Comment: *Why* are you trying to create an array of vectors? Or alternatively, why not `std::array<std::vector<int>, 5>`?

Comment: `new vector<int>[5]` **does** create 5 *empty* `vector<int>`s. Why do you think it has created only one?

Comment: @qoinqoder sure, in that case you create a vector and do : `vector<vector<int>>* ptr = &vec` so create a pointer and point it to the original vector.... still not sure why you need new.

Comment: I need new because the value inside brackets are received as an input. maybe, I should update the it as N.

Comment: In that case, look at @SamerTufail's first comment.

Comment: @qoinqoder then you can use `vector<vector<int>>(N,vector<int>(N,0))`, still would do what you are describing it should do without doing `new`

Comment: I understand that vector<vector<int>> would do the work for me. 
Its just a curiosity to know how memory is being allocated and why is it not the same as built-in data types?

Comment: It is not a data type its a container holding data. You are now going away from the niceties of auto memory mangement and making your life difficult.

Comment: @qoinqoder after you editted your question, the premise of your question is now wrong. `new vector<int>[V];` does create an array of vectors. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: One difference: You can't change the size of `[]` arrays, you can only replace them with different ones. And that's (an approximation) of what vector does, when you grow it

Comment: "It is not a data type its a container holding data." This is what I was looking for. Maybe a more elaborate answer. Thanks @Samuel.

Comment: _Why does “new vector<int>[5]” not create an array of vectors?_ It does.

Answer (score 2):

This here:

```
int *arr = new int(5);
```

Does not make an array of `5` `int`s. It makes one `int` and initializes it to `5`. What you wanted instead is:

```
int *arr = new int[5];
```

Similarly, with the vector, you want this:

```
vector<int> *arr = new vector<int>[5];
```

The code `new vector<int>(5);` would instead make one vector with a size pre-set to `5`.

Comment: I have updated (corrected the bracket []), please review the question once. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The assumption is wrong.

```
new vector<int>[5]
```

creates an array of 5 elements of type `vector<int>`.

This code is valid:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> *v = new std::vector<int>[5];
    v[0].push_back(1);
    v[0].push_back(2);
    v[0].push_back(3);
    v[0].push_back(4);
    v[3].push_back(31);
    v[3].push_back(32);
    std::cout << v[0][1] << '\n';
    std::cout << v[0][2] << '\n';
    std::cout << v[3][1] << '\n';
    std::cout << v[4].size() << '\n';
    delete[] v;
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is

```
2
3
32
0
```